# Passwords not working anymore?

Tags: passwords, login

I'm having a strange problem. I just opened up Twitch to play some Minecraft but it asked me for my credentials again. After filling them out it said they where incorrect. So I changed the password and tried again without luck. I hooked MC up to my secondary email. So I figured I might have switched that to my primary a while back.

So I wanted to login on my primary hotmail account and my password was wrong here too. So I changed my password for hotmail too, and exactly the same issue turned up. With the new password I cannot login either.

Does anyone know what is going on? I'm using Lastpass but I also filled out passwords manually. I'm afraid I will lose access to more accounts.

Comment: Have you run an antivirus?

Comment: @Xavierjazz Avast free, now you mentioned that it said there is a update.

Comment: @Xavierjazz after a update and restart I can get into my email and MC account again. Weird, you think it had anything to do with Avira?

Comment: @Madmenyo Updating Acura has nothing to do with you being unable to access Minecraft account.  It sounds like these accounts password have been legitimately been changed